# C++ Random Function making smiley faces

Tags: c++, random

I am working on a battleship c++ program. I am testing out how I want to go about setting the ships and the water. I have an array and I create a random number for each int inside the array using a for loop. The random number it generates is a smiley face.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int picks = 0;
    char arena[25] = {};
    for(int i = 0; i != 24; i++) {
        srand(time(0));
        picks = rand() % 3;
        arena[i] = picks;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i != 24; i++)
    cout << arena[i];
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i != 24; i++) {
        if(arena[i] = 1)
            cout << "~";
        else if(arena[i] = 2)
            cout << "~";
        else if(arena[i] = 3)
            cout << "#";
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: `srand(time(0))` put this before the start of the loop

Comment: When the program outputs arena[i], the ascii characters 1, 2 will display as smiley faces, 1 is black on white, 2 is white on black. 0 should leave blank spot on screen.

Comment: You are printing binary codes as characters. Print them as numerics: `%d` and you'll see you have the numbers you expect.

Comment: Omg i should've noticed that sorry for the derp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are generating values between 0 and 2, and assigning them to elements of a *character* array, so that when they get printed out, characters with those codes (on of which is, apparently, a smiley face) is printed.  It isn't clear what you really want instead, but in case you are expecting to print a `0` for each value of 0, then you can print `(arena[i]+'0')` instead (or, better, properly format the output as others have suggested).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I should have noticed that!

Answer (score 1):

1.Put the `srand(time(NULL))` before the loop.
2.`picks = rand() % 3` ==> `picks = rand() % 3 + 1`
3.`if (arena[i] = 1)` ==> `if (arena[i] == 1)`